# Excess noise in cycles render and odd denoising results

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, denoise, noise-reduction

I'm trying to do some renders of a dark room, but there's quite a bit of noise despite me setting it to 128 samples. When the denoiser kicks in, it fixes the noise but makes the scene look completely bizarre. Is there a fix for this without remaking the scene with different lighting?[image]

[image]

Comment: 128 samlpes is a very low value. Try 1000.

Comment: Agree with susu. Also try the denoise node in the compositor instead of this other one.

Comment: I'm currently using the intel AI denoiser, is that the right one?